# Casting into a class that has no default constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Is it possible in Java to cast an object that has no default constructor? If yes, how?

Comment: You need to provide more details--are you asking something different? Ctors have nothing to do with casting.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't possible?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as any other cast.

A cast does not create a new object, it only tells the compiler to treat a reference as an object of a given class.

So, you have

```
 Object obj = new String("Hi");
 String k = obj;
```

The second line is invalid because it assigns a superclass to a more specific reference, so you have to tell the compiler that `obj` is *really* an object instance of String.

```
 String k = (String) obj;
```

---

And here is a contrived example that illustrates the point without default constructors:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(int i) { ; }
}

public class Bar extends Foo
{
  public Bar(int i, String s) { super(i); }
}

final Foo foo = new Bar(42, "Arthur");
final Bar bar = (Bar) foo;
```

Comment: Both String and Object have default ctors.

Comment: Which, as I said in the first line, is completely irrelevant when it comes to casting...

Comment: Great, but if you're going to show an example, maybe it should be relevant--just an idea. Otherwise you're not really demonstrating the truth of what you're saying.

Comment: Factual inaccuracy in 2nd sentence.  (It doesn't ONLY tell the compiler that.  It ALSO causes runtime checking code to be inserted ... depending on whether this is an upcast or downcast.)

Comment: For the above example, what happens when you want to cast an object into Foo? Lets say you have Object obj=new Object(); Can you cast obj into Foo?

Comment: @ncoder no, because `obj` is not really an instance of `Foo` (an object has the class that you used for the `new`). It would fail (ClassCastException). You only cast objects that already **are** an instance of the casted class.

Comment: Thank you SJuan, This answers my initial question.